# NSComparisonResult misbehaving

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

my application is comparing strings of requests sent to a function, like `-(void)sendSearchRequest:(NSString *)request sport:(NSString *)sport location:(NSString *)location`. I'm setting the request to 'Kevin', the **sport to 'Baseball**' and the location to 'Wellston'.

Then, I'm comparing it against an object whose request is 'Kevin', sp**ort is 'Basketball'**, and location is 'Wellston'. The sport should return false, but it isn't. Whats going on?

```
   for (Athlete *athlete in self.athletes) {


    NSComparisonResult result = [[athlete name] compare:request options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [request length])];
      NSComparisonResult sportCompare = [[athlete sport] compare:sport options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [sport length])];
    NSComparisonResult locationCompare = [location compare:self.cityName options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.cityName length])];

    NSLog(@"Location: %@", location);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", request);
    NSLog(@"Sport: %@", sport);
    if (result == NSOrderedSame && sportCompare == NSOrderedSame && locationCompare == NSOrderedSame) {



        [self.filteredArray addObject:athlete];
                  }
}
```

**Notes:**
* I have to take account for user error. These variables are being passed from a UITextField, so if a user enters 'Wellston, OK' but the object's city is 'Wellston', it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know whether two strings are the same, why are you using NSComparisonResult? That makes no sense at all. It is for *sorting*. Just use `isEqualToString:` - that's what it's for.

Or for more a more sophisticated notion of equality, you can implement an anchored substring search. You can make that case-insensitive and diacritic-insensitive. Thus you can determine whether one string starts with another, for example.

Comment: I knew this would come up, but I have to take account for user error. These variables are being passed from a UITextField, so if a user enters 'Wellston, OK' but the object's city is 'Wellston', it won't work.

Comment: But then how will `compare` help you solve that? It seems to me that what you want is an anchored substring search. You can make that case-insensitive and diacritic-insensitive.

Comment: I've never heard of that, most of what I've seen is just NsComparisonResult, I'll take a look into that.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html "Case-insensitive search for prefix and suffix"

Comment: Of course, no simple-minded solution is going to solve the "Wellston" problem. If the user is to be granted that kind of leeway, you need serious artificial intelligence here... However, that is not the question you asked.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the tip, my solution ended up being:   if (result == NSOrderedSame && [athlete.sport == sport] == true && [sport caseInsensitiveCompare:[athlete sport]]) {

Comment: The sport field is from a picker, so it can be compared.